# Matthew 3:11: "With water" or "In water"?

Tags: greek

I wonder how most translations ended up chosing "with" for ἐν, rather than "in", in verses like Matthew 3:11, Mark 1:8, Luke 3:16, John 1:26;31;33, Acts 1:5 and 11:16. "Immerse in water" sounds like a whole lot more logical than "immerse with water", which I am not even sure is proper English?

Comment: That's really a minor question compared to why translators transliterate βαπτίζω instead of translating it.

Comment: That too :) In Norwegian we use an old word, "døpe", which means "dip", in todays language "dyppe". I do not believe it is immediately clear to everyone that this word really means that, but it is in my opinion better than transliterating the greek.

Comment: @PerryWebb Probably because, like other words, it had a technical usage (i.e. as the name of a sacrament). First century document written in Greek, the Didache, (circa 70AD) speaks of baptism thus; "And concerning baptism, baptize this way: Having first said all these things, baptize in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit, in living water. But if you have not living water, baptize in other water; and if you can not in cold, in warm. But if you have not either, pour out water thrice upon the head in the name of Father and Son and Holy Spirit."

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this correct - most versions prefer to translate the Greek "ἐν" in Matt 3:11 by "with".  Some exceptions that use "in" are: NHEB, Aramaic, JB2000, ASV, DRB, Weymouth, WEB.

BDAG lists twelve primary meanings of the Greek proposition "ἐν", the fifth meaning is, "**marker introducing a means or instrument, *with***".  However, Matt 3:11 is not listed as an example.  Examples included under this heading are: Luke 14:31, Jude 14, 1 Cor 4:21, Matt 16:28, Heb 9:25, etc.

Despite this possibility, I would still prefer "in".

Answer (score 0):

Towards Sola Gratia, no where in the New Testament letters was pouring or sprinkling of water on the head an acceptable baptism practice, the very Greek word baptizo means immersion and the Baptism of repentance was only done so if there was deep enough water in order to immerse fully the body.

Comment: An answer is not the place to debate something someone else said, unless it is part of your own point...in an answer to the question above. My point in quoting a first century Christian catechism written in Greek was to show 'baptism' already had a technically usage then; it didn't only mean to 'dip' simply because that's the immediate or literal sense of the word baptize. Also, the Bible doesn't teach what constitutes a valid baptism anyway, it only gives examples of baptisms. it doesn't restrict the method; and as you can see, Jewish Christians who spoke Greek practiced baptism thus A.D. 70.

Comment: The example recorded and the choice words used in context to describe that example is the instructed method.and sense no other methods were recorded or spoken of then we must go by what was left to us in context and eyewitness accounts. Anywhere there is a wrong idea of what God allows or says must be addressed regardless the enviroment or setting.